# Get the image width inside a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="divclass">
    <ul>
      <div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img1.jpg"/></li> </div>
      <div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img2.jpg"/></li> </div>
      <div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img3.jpg"/></li> </div>
      <div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img4.jpg"/></li> </div>
      <div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img5.jpg"/></li> </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How i get the image width? All images are in  different width. I want to get the image width and i give it to the div class="lidiv". Any one can help? please!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have a `div` as a direct child of `ul`.

Comment: change `<div class="lidiv"> <li><img src="img1.jpg"/></li> </div>` to    `<li><div class="lidiv"> <img src="img1.jpg"/></div></li> `

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.divClass ul li img').width();
```

This code should works. But Rory McCrossan is right, your html is invalid. The browser may remove the `div` tag inside the `li`, so you can access it in javascript.

But you can give a width to the `li` tag :

```
$('.divClass ul li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    $li.width($li.find('img').width());
});
```

Warning : On some browser, the DOMReady event is fired before the image loading ! So if you get a 0 width (or `undefined`), you should execute this code later. You can listen to the images load event :

```
$('.divClass ul li img').load(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    $img.parent().width($img.width());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First loop over de div-items. Then select the descendant img-element. After getting the image width, put it in the css-style of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("div.lidiv").each(function() { 
        img = $(this).find('img');
        img_width = img.width();
        $(this).css('width', img_width);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the image visible on the page? I get also 0 width, but that's because it can not load the image I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var imgWidth = jQuery('img').clientWidth;
```

and write valid HTML.

Comment: I changed the html and it's not working. It displays undefined.